# ASP.NET Core routing prefix

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, routes

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application. My application hosted with NGinx on url `http://somedomain.com/MyApplication`.

I need all requests routed to prefix `/MyApplication`.

My problem with controllers actions responses redirects to `somedomain.com`, not to `somedomain.com/MyApplication`.

Is there any way to configure routes to use prefix `/MyApplication`?

UPD: for example

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
```

redirects to somedomain.com, but i need to somedomain.com/MyApplication

Comment: How are you generating the URLs that should contain the "/MyApplication" but don't?

Comment: I would not put this logic inside ASPCore application. Rather make the nginx strip out the prefix `/MyApplication` and pass what matters to the application.

Comment: I would see if I could find an Nginx way of solving this. The mapping of incoming requests to /MyApplication is done by Nginx and it should also be Nginx's responsibility to modify any URLs in the responses. If you make your C# program aware that Nginx is modifying incoming requests, then you need to keep Nginx and your app in sync and that is asking for problems.

Answer (score 35):

you can use the `PathBase` middleware just before `Mvc` like this :

```
partial class Startup {

    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IHostingEnvironment env
    ) {
        app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/MyApplication"));
        app.UseMvc();
    }

}
```

with the `PathBase` middleware, no need to change any mvc code, it will automatically add to the request and response.

please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions.usepathbase?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything in asp.net core 6.... weird.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka No, it is supported from 2.1 to 6.0. <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions.usepathbase?view=aspnetcore-6.0>

Comment: Turns out it's a bit of a bug in 6. Workaround is to call `app.UseRouting()` explicitly. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38448

Comment: This did it for me, thanks.
Ideally you should be able to solve this through nginx but at least you can use a parameter in appsettings to store the base path. If the parameter is not null just set it like this. No need to change static files paths or controller routing like most solutions I've found.

Comment: It works, but order matters. Need to set it before UseMvc(), or other equivalents.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38448#issuecomment-1003242330

Answer (score 6):

If you are using MVC, you can try to change the default route format.
In `Startup.cs` replace the line

```
app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); });
```

with this one:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "MyApplication/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); });
```

Let me know if it's what you need

Answer (score 4):

```
[Route("MyApplication")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Blah!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In App_Start/RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    url: "MyApplication/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute routing for ASP.NET Core.In the below example shows

```
[Route("MyApplication")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    //You can have multiple routes on an action
    [Route("")] /MyApplication
    [Route("/test")] you have move to the /MyApplication/test 
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        //Your Code Session
    }
}
```

OR you use
Attribute routing with Http[Verb] attributes.
To be add the path in [HttpGet("Your Path")],In the case of [HttpPost("Your Path")].

```
[HttpGet("/MyApplication")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
```