# how to change net core router prefix

Tags: asp.net-core

I have net core app which was deployed on linux,how can I change router api prefix by config.
it's like this https://localhost/api/index --> https://localhost/appName/api/index.
How can I add appname to router and don't change code.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `StartUp` Configuration file change the routing to add your AppName. There are several ways to do it (depending on you'r app being an web API or MVC). You can find all of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473486/asp-net-core-routing-prefix)

Comment: @honore What do you mean by that?