# ASPNET Core 3.1 Razor Pages with virtual directory in kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have two web sites developed using Aspnet core 3.1 Razor Pages, hosted by kestrel. Example:

```
https://localhost:50001/*
https://localhost:50002/*
```

There is no problem when running in debug mode. However in production I would like to do the old IIS method where we can add a virtual directory to the URL. Example:

```
https://example.com/MyAppA/*
https://example.com/MyAppB/*
```

I knew kestrel cannot do this, but I can't use IIS as well because I need to deploy these web site in non windows environment.

May I know if it is possible for me to modify the routing in Razor Pages to add the **MyAppA** or **MyAppB** in my code?

The simplest way of doing so is to move all the pages in [solution]\Pages\* to [solution]\Pages\MyAppA\*, but I will keep this as an last option.

Thanks

Comment: Are those websites in different ASP.NET projets? If so, you might need a reverse proxy to handle the requests before forwarded them to the services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `PathBase` middleware, please try the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57494684/4076996

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddRazorPages(options =>
      {
           //this is page level so you need to add every page
           options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/index", "MyAppA");
           options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/test1", "MyAppA/test1");
      });
}
```

Comment: This is only change the default root directory to MyAppA (means MyAppA must exist prior to this setting), but not appending the MyAppA into the URL